# How can i disable the next/previous photo buttons in Lightbox2?

Tags: php, lightbox2

The reason i want to do this is because when I am on a timeline and click a photo of a post, Lightbox2 modal opens and i have that next and previous buttons.

I have disabled the "image x out of x" showing under every photo but i can't find a way for the buttons.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each of your images has a different value for the data-lightbox attribute. If they all have the same value, a "set" is created and the next/prev buttons will appear.

**Example**

```
<a href="image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image1">1</a>
<a href="image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="image2">2</a>
```